# VC inside another VC that is not getting button presses(after moving to XCode8)

Tags: ios, objective-c

This was all working while I was using Xcode 6.4. I installed macOS Sierra and Xcode 8 on my machine and this has become broken.

I have a Viewcontroller (vc1) with a UIView on it. Inside this UIView I load another Viewcontroller (vc2).

Now the button interactions on vc2 are no longer processed. I've added new buttons and methods as a sanity check and they are not getting the press signals either. Made sure they were all connected up in the XIB and they are.

Has anybody come across this before and know the solution?

Many Thanks,
C

Comment: Did you load your Vc2 as a subview or as a childViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be problem with your Vc2 frame.

Try to set frame of your Vc2 manually like below code.

```
UIStoryboard *sb =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL];
SecondVC *Vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idSecondVC"];
Vc.view.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.containerVw.frame.size.width,self.containerVw.frame.size.height);
[self.containerVw addSubview:Vc.view];
[self addChildViewController:Vc];//adding your Vc2 as a childViewController
```

containerVw -> Your UIView of Vc1 in which you are adding your Vc2 as a subview.

Comment: [self.myUIView addSubview:childViewController.view]; self.UIView is a UIView that is a property of Vc1. childViewController.view is Vc2.

Comment: Thanks Raj setting the frame fixed the problem. Just note this issue only appeared when moving from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 8. If I moved the .xib from an old copy of the project that was never opened in Xcode8 and didn't open the file itself in the Xcode8, just built the project the button worked. Opening the xib caused some changes to be made and the problem appears.

Comment: @Code This seems to be the weird issue with Xcode8, although i haven't face such type of issue, but thanks for info.